# How to capture the screen and pass it as background for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, screenshot, screen-capture

.I need to capture the screen (screenshot) when I click on a button and place it as a background in a div. I have found a few methods for screen capture but none of them do this for me.
Sorry if it sounds strange or it is an odd question.

Lets say I have something like this:

```
    $( "#MyButton" ).click(function() {

//some code to capture the screen

      var MyVar = "url(captured.jpg) no-repeat"
      $(".MyDiv").css("background", MyVar);

});
```

So if I click on MyButton "some code to capture the screen" takes a screenshot, places it in as a url in MyVar, so it becomes the background image for MyDiv. Is it even possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use html to canvas 
I'm not sure that's the best to use in your scenario or not

Take a look at demo [here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas)

You need to include three js
jquery-1.10.2.min.js,html2canvas.js,jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js

Function demo

```
    function captureCurrentscreen() {
            html2canvas($('body'),{
                onrendered: function (canvas) {                     
                            var imgString = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                            window.open(imgString);                  
            }
        });

$( "#MyButton" ).click(function() {

captureCurrentscreen();

      var MyVar = "url(captured.jpg) no-repeat"
      $(".MyDiv").css("background", MyVar);

});
```

This will help you